Invariant Violation:TurboModuleRegistry.getEnforcing(...):'RNGestureHandlerModule' could not be found
Adding Navigation container and navigators to nx monorepo react native project is giving this error even after installing reactnative gesturehandler:
Invariant Violation: TurboModuleRegistry.getEnforcing(...): 'RNGestureHandlerModule' could not be found. Verify that a module by this name is registered in the native binary.
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, SafeAreaView } from 'react-native';
import { theme } from '@NxDemo/theme';
import { HomeScreen, Profile } from '@NxDemo/ui-components';
import { AppNavigationContainer, TabNavigator } from '@NxDemo/navigation';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <AppNavigationContainer>
        <TabNavigator
          screens={[
            { name: 'Home', component: HomeScreen },
            { name: 'Profile', component: Profile },
          ]}
          initialRouteName="Home"
        />
      </AppNavigationContainer>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default App;


This is my metro.config.js file
const { withNxMetro } = require('@nx/react-native');
const { getDefaultConfig, mergeConfig } = require('@react-native/metro-config');

const defaultConfig = getDefaultConfig(__dirname);
const { assetExts, sourceExts } = defaultConfig.resolver;

/**
 * Metro configuration
 * https://reactnative.dev/docs/metro
 *
 * @type {import('metro-config').MetroConfig}
 */
const customConfig = {
  transformer: {
    babelTransformerPath: require.resolve('react-native-svg-transformer'),
  },
  resolver: {
    assetExts: assetExts.filter((ext) => ext !== 'svg'),
    sourceExts: [...sourceExts, 'cjs', 'mjs', 'svg'],
  },
};

module.exports = withNxMetro(mergeConfig(defaultConfig, customConfig), {
  // Change this to true to see debugging info.
  // Useful if you have issues resolving modules
  debug: false,
  // all the file extensions used for imports other than 'ts', 'tsx', 'js', 'jsx', 'json'
  extensions: [],
  // Specify folders to watch, in addition to Nx defaults (workspace libraries and node_modules)
  watchFolders: [],
});


I want to add Tab navigation to nx monorepo react native project and this error is coming up: Invariant Violation: TurboModuleRegistry.getEnforcing(...): 'RNGestureHandlerModule' could not be found. Verify that a module by this name is registered in the native binary.
I already have "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.16.2", this dependency in package.json

Did you found any solution sravanth ?
